# Recent directory missing

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, files

Today 16.04 told me that a new version was available (18.04) and I decided to try it. I can't measure it, but 18.04 seems a little snappier.

But my Recent directory no longer appears in my list. I used that *all the time*.

How can I get it back?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 18.04 go to Settings → Privacy → Usage & History and ensure it is set to `On`.

[image]

Even if it set to `On` click on the option and make sure that the `Recently Used` option in Usage & History is also set to `ON`

[image]

Order should then be restored. At the same time, you can also set the `Retain History` period as required - I think in your case set `Forever`and should you need to tidy things up, click on the `Clear Recent History` button.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.  Unfortunately it didn't work. I saw that setting yesterday somewhere after the post, but it didn't work. Checked it again following your answer in case I missed something.

I'm on a System76 Oryx Pro laptop, 64bit, 16 RAM, Intel Core i7-7700 HQ, 2.8GHzx8.

When I installed 18.04 I did NOT replace config files or remove obsolete packages. I can't find any directory called [Rr]ecent.

What else can I check?

Comment: @Lew With Nautilus open go to the top bar next to Activities and click the down arrow next to Files. Deselect Sidebar and then again to reset it to if that works. Your version of Nautilus appears different to the standard one with v18.04 and Gnome?

Comment: thanks. I didn't see a down arrow. But I did find another "Files" program that lists Recent at the top, and it lists files I've opened recently. Its left nav pane has a black background, and the icons are plain folders without music notes, person silhouettes, etc.  (can't add screen clip to a comment). I remember choosing the other one a couple years ago (I forget why) and noting the identical name. **I'll use this new one unless I run into trouble with it.** Thanks again.

Comment: @Lew Thanks for the feedback. Pity my solution didn't entirely work for your issue but it will probably be ok for someone else. :)

Comment: Seems that the file manager I've been using is Nemo. So apparently that's the one that has lost Recent in 18.04

Comment: So I can use Nemo in 18.04 if I don't need its old Recent function. Nautilus has Recent, but you can't sort files in its displays.

Comment: @Lew Click the down arrow next to Files in the top bar (with Nautilus open) and select Preferences. There are options there to sort files under the List Columns tab.

Comment: Thanks @graham I'm getting used to it.